# Access TFS on Server on Local Network (Domain)

Tags: iis, tfs, windows-server

I have a local server that is set up on a domain. Before I started running it on a domain, I was able to access Team Foundation Server from another machine on my local network. Once I put the server on a domain setup, I became unable to access TFS from outside of the server itself. I can still access it when I'm on the server (`http://localhost/tfs/`), but I cannot access it from my other machine (`http://servername/tfs` or `http://serverIP/tfs`). Is there something I need to change in my Team Foundation Server configuration or my server itself in order to allow access to this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that TFS configured the Firewall to allow access on private networks only. To fix, I just had to add the Domain permission as well.

Comment: If you did not follow the documented instructions for "moving tfs to a new configuration" then you are likely in for a bunch of other problems...

Comment: I've been successfully using it since the change. The only problem I had was accessing it. Since I didn't actually move anything, I'm wondering if this is the same thing as what you're saying. I haven't had problems checking in changes, browsing to TFS itself, adding and associating work items, etc.

Comment: It is the same as what I am saying. Although you did not physically more is (there is another process for that) you did move from non-domain to domain. That is an environment change, even if it was in place.